# spring-security-saml 2.0 - how to register all the users in the system?

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0

I'ld like to implement SSO using SAML 2.0 in my web applications. I have seen spring-security-saml example [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml.git]. There are a couple of things I wanted to know after I went through this sample:

1. Do I have to redirect all the user-registratons to the registration page of IDP as in this sample ? If not, how does the IDP know the credentials of the user?
2. Do the IDPs' like ssocircle (used in this sample) allow us to use customized attributes and change password kind of scenarios ?
3. What is the best IDP to use to implement saml sso in my application ?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q.** Do I have to redirect all the user-registratons to the registration page of IDP as in this sample?

In SAML parlance, an application can be an identity provider (IDP) or a service provider (SP).  An IDP authenticates users, which means that user identities and credentials are maintained by the IDP.  An SP provides one or more service to the user.

From your question, it seems that you want to delegate the task of authenticating users of your application to an external party (the IDP).  Therefore, your application will be the SP.

With that established, you will have to redirect all users to the IDP for authentication.  The IDP's authentication page may have a link to the registration page, if required.

> **Q.** How does the IDP know the credentials of the user?

The user must be registered with the IDP (after all, the purpose of the IDP is to authoritatively authenticate a user's identity, which it cannot do if the user is not registered with it).  Users can be self-registered or registered by an administrator, such as, a Microsoft Active Directory Domain Administrator.

> **Q.** What if I need to register the user in my system as well since I need to assign them roles specific to my system?

You can create your own implementation of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` wherein you can check the authenticated user on successful single sign-on and register them with your application.  Supply an instance of your implementation class as the redirect handler to the SAML entry point.

Do note that you will not have access to the user's password since that is stored by the IDP.

> **Q.** Do the IDP's like SSOCircle allow us to use customized attributes?

SSOCircle is mostly a testing service for SSO (single sign-on).  Although SAML supports custom attributes, SSOCircle only supports `FirstName`, `LastName` and `EmailAddress` (as of February 2016).  Therefore no, you cannot use other custom attributes with SSOCircle.

Actual IDP's like Okta, OneLogin or Microsoft ADFS do support custom attributes.  You must check their respective documentation for configuring and exchanging custom attributes between the IDP and the SP.

> **Q.** Do the IDP's like SSOCircle support change-password kind of scenarios?

I am not sure about SSOCircle but an actual IDP will be a system that already has user identity management capabilities.  Since password change is a common functionality for an identity management system, this should be supported with an actual IDP.  However, you should consult the documentation for the actual IDP you use to make sure.

> **Q.** What is the best IDP to use for my SAML application?

An IDP is not a product or a specification, making this question somewhat invalid.  It is simply a type of actor in the SAML universe.  If your users are part of a Microsoft Windows Active Directory forest, you can use [Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) to exchange SAML messages between Active Directory and your (SP) application(s).

If you want to support multiple Active Directory forests, or if you do not know in advance where your users will be, you can use delegation-based services like [Okta](https://www.okta.com) or [OneLogin](http://www.onelogin.com/), which allow your application to take incoming assertions from the delegation service.